# How to add code to a method

Tags: java, arrays, json, api, parsing

Hello I just want to ask how should i get the codes function into a method which is run by the main at the moment! Basically so that I can activate the working method from the main instead. I am new to programming so I am having quite a bit of trouble grasping everything properly

```
    package bla_bla;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.*;
    import javax.swing.text.html.parser.Element;

        import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
        import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
        import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
        import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
        import org.jsoup.select.Evaluator.Id;
        import org.json.*;

        import argo.saj.InvalidSyntaxException;

        public class supermonkey {

        private static ArrayList<BugsList> bugsList;    
        private static ArrayList<BugsList> bugbug;  


        public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

            bugsList = new ArrayList<BugsList>();
            bugbug = new ArrayList<BugsList>();
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/rest/bug?product=Input&f1=bug_mentor&o1=isnotempty").get();
            String rawData = doc.body().text();
        //  System.out.println(title);
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(rawData);

        //  System.out.println(obj);

            System.out.println(obj.get("bugs"));

            JSONArray jsonMainArr = new JSONArray(obj.get("bugs").toString());
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainArr.length(); i++) {  // **line 2**
                 JSONObject childJSONObject = jsonMainArr.getJSONObject(i);
                 JSONObject assigned = childJSONObject.getJSONObject("assigned_to_detail");
              //   JSONObject assigned2 = childJSONObject.getJSONObject("assigned_to_detail");


                 int id = assigned.getInt("id");
                 BugsList bug = new BugsList();
                 BugsList bug2 = new BugsList();
                 bug.setId(id);



                 String severity = childJSONObject.getString("severity");
                 String resolution = childJSONObject.getString("resolution");
                 String summary = childJSONObject.getString("summary");
                 String component = childJSONObject.getString("component");
                 bug.setSeverity(severity);
                 bug.setResolution(resolution);
                 bug.setSummary(summary);
                 bug.setComponent(component);
                 bugsList.add(bug);

                 // String severity = assigned.getString();
        //       System.out.println("sss  "+ assigned);

            }



            getComponent("Code Quality");
        //  getSeverity(524276);
        //  getResolution(524276);
        //  getSummary(524276);
        }
           public static void getSeverity(int id){
               for(int i =0;i<bugsList.size(); i++){
                   if(bugsList.get(i).getId() == id){
                       System.out.println("The id exists in the list " + bugsList.get(i).getSeverity());
                   }
               }
           } 

           public static void getResolution(int id){
               for(int i =0;i<bugsList.size(); i++){
                   if(bugsList.get(i).getId() == id){
                       System.out.println("The id exists in the list and The resolution is" + bugsList.get(i).getResolution());
                   }
               }
           }  

           public static void getSummary(int id){
               for(int i =0;i<bugsList.size(); i++){
                   if(bugsList.get(i).getId() == id){
        System.out.println("The comp.. exists in the list and The summary is   " + bugsList.get(i).getSummary());
                   }
               }
           }
            // Current used method
           public static ArrayList<BugsList> getComponent(String component){
               for(int i =0;i<bugsList.size(); i++){
                   if(bugsList.get(i).getComponent().equals(component)){
                       System.out.println("(Code Quality) component contains summary  " + bugsList.get(i).getSummary() +" /The resolution is " +                 
        bugsList.get(i).getResolution() + "  /Severity is " + bugsList.get(i).getSeverity());
                       bugbug.add(bugsList.get(i));
                   }
               }
               return bugbug;
           }   


        }

  package bla_bla;

public class BugsList {

    private String severity;
    private int id; 
    private String resolution;
    private String summary;
    private String component;

    public String getComponent() {
        return component;
    }
    public void setComponent(String component) {
        this.component = component;
    }
    public String getSummary() {
        return summary;
    }
    public void setSummary(String summary) {
        this.summary = summary;
    }
    public String getResolution() {
        return resolution;
    }
    public void setResolution(String resolution) {
        this.resolution = resolution;
    }
    public String getSeverity() {
        return severity;
    }
    public void setSeverity(String severity) {
        this.severity = severity;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }   
}
```

Comment: What's the problem/question?

Comment: It's hard to understand what you are trying to do in your code. Can you please cut-down only to problem area?

Comment: Here is the result what i get below. Now if you go to the api website that I am using in my code to drag down the data. You will see for every different component(Code Quality, General etc). There are various types of summary, severity, resolution given. The result you see down below are all the search results for a specified component. What i would like to have at the end is that the user can have each bug information numbered as an array, instead of all them coming as jumble.

Comment: (Code Quality) component contains summary  Use Django's forms for dashboard controls, instead of reinventing the wheel. /The resolution is WONTFIX  /Severity is normal
(Code Quality) component contains summary  update south /The resolution is FIXED  /Severity is normal
(Code Quality) component contains summary  make utility modules in apps consistent /The resolution is FIXED  /Severity is normal

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand you problem. You write your code into the main function and that not the solution. 
Your main function should look something like that:

```
     public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {        
        Supermonkey supermonkey = new Supermonkey();
        supermonkey.getComponent("componennt name ");
    }
```

Your Class is Supermonkey and you create an instance call supermonkey (sometime people use mySupermonkey) . There is only one instance of this class that will use.

Then into the constructor method you can create everything to build your instance supermonkey as :

```
    public class Supermonkey {

    private  ArrayList<BugsList> bugsList;
    private  ArrayList<BugsList> bugbug;

    public Supermonkey(){
        bugsList = new ArrayList<BugsList>();
        bugbug = new ArrayList<BugsList>();
        Document doc = Jsoup
                .connect(
                        "https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/rest/bug?product=Input&f1=bug_mentor&o1=isnotempty")
                .get();
        String rawData = doc.body().text(); // ... partial code add everything about initialisation of your instance
```

Then you can have a method of this Class Supermonkey

```
        // Current used method
    public  ArrayList<BugsList> getComponent(String component) {
        for (int i = 0; i < bugsList.size(); i++) {
            if (bugsList.get(i).getComponent().equals(component)) {
                System.out
                        .println("(Code Quality) component contains summary  "
                                + bugsList.get(i).getSummary()
                                + " /The resolution is "
                                + bugsList.get(i).getResolution()
                                + "  /Severity is "
                                + bugsList.get(i).getSeverity());
                bugbug.add(bugsList.get(i));
            }
        }
        return bugbug;
    }
```

A this method is call from the `public static void main(String args[])` with `supermonkey.getComponent("componennt name ");`

Also I think about to change the name of Class `BugsList` it seems to be a `BugItem` , may be ?